# Problems with select component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I'm having a problem submitting my list of items from my select, I'm starting with angular and still a little lost. This is my first post here!

In my HTML I use ng-repeat to list all items, and when my screen loads my first and only item is: `{{list.name}}`, when I click on this item `{{list.name}}`, ai loads the List correctly.

```
<select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Empresa/Filial" multiple chosen
    style="width: 100%;"
    ng-model="filtroRequisicao.codigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais"
    required>
    <option ng-repeat="list in lista" ng-value="list.id">
         {{list.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Angularjs:

```
$scope.lista = [{}];

    //Carrega as Filiais dos Cooperados
        $scope.loadFiliais = function () {
            var usuario = localStorage.getItem("usuarioAutenticado");
            var objetoUsuario = {};

            objetoUsuario = JSON.parse(usuario);


            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/getFiliais',
                data: objetoUsuario
            }).then(function (response) {

                    $scope.lista = response.data;

                    console.log($scope.lista);
                },

                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.showNoty('Nenhum dado encontrado.', 'information');
                });
        };

        $scope.loadFiliais();
```

One thing I realized was starting my list off of a method PUT call from angular.

```
$scope.lista =
            [
                {
                    'id': 1,
                    'name': 'American Black Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'name': 'Asiatic Black Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 3,
                    'name': 'Brown Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 4,
                    'name': 'Giant Panda',
                },
                {
                    'id': 5,
                    'name': 'Sloth Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 6,
                    'name': 'Sun Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 7,
                    'name': 'Polar Bear',
                },
                {
                    'id': 8,
                    'name': 'Spectacled Bear',
                }
            ];
```

When I fill values out of a function, as an example, my select shows all items. Now if I populate the values inside the return from my angular PUT (response.data), my select gets no items.

It seems to me that the html is being loaded before I even finish loading all my controller in the angle.

I do not know if I'm looking the wrong way, but it seems to me a problem and I do not know how to solve

**UPDATE**

CSS

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendor/angular/angular-csp.css"/>
```

form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <p class="lt-label-required">Situação</p>
   <select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Empresa/Filial" multiple class="chosen ng-cloak" chosen style="width: 100%;"
       ng-model="filtroRequisicao.codigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais"
       required>

       <option ng-repeat="list in lista" value="{{list.id}}">
             {{list.name}}
       </option>

    </select>
 </div>
```

angular:

```
$scope.loadFiliais= function () {
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/getFiliais'
            }).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.lista = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.lista);
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.showNoty('Nenhum dado encontrado.', 'information');
                });
        };

        $scope.loadFiliais();
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

I was able to solve my problem, but I would like your help to know if this is the correct way:

I used ng-if so that when my `$scope.lista` is null-dir, ng-if will remove and re-create the elemento.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Angular:

```
$scope.lista = [];
```

Html:

```
    <select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Empresa/Filial" multiple chosen
        style="width: 100%;"
        ng-if="lista.length > 0"
        ng-model="filtroRequisicao.codigoSistemaUsuariosFiliais"
        required>
        <option ng-repeat="list in lista" ng-value="list.id">
             {{list.name}}
        </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

1. Putting ng-cloak to the body or to the tag takes care of the {{list.name}} issue.
2. Making $scope.lista = [] and using ng-if inside the select with

   ```
   ng-if="lista.length > 0"
   ```

   solves the issue of rendering the select options.

Put an ng-cloak to the body or to the tag.

Read about it here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.

This will take care of the {{list.name}} issue.

Make $scope.lista = [] not [{}];

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I added the css with in my index.html as per the documentation, I placed the ng-cloak class in my select: `code`<select data-placeholder="Escolha uma Situação" multiple class="chosen" chosen style="width: 100%;"ng-model="multipleSelect"  required  class="ng-cloak">
<option ng-repeat="list in listaDocumentoSituacoes" value="{{list.id}}">
{{list.name}}</option></select>`code` and initialized my # scope.list = []; And now {{list.name}} is gone, the select is empty

Comment: does it solves the issue ? You can try adding `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.loadFiliais();`

Comment: It did not solve it, neither with ng-cloak nor with $ scope.apply, the following error occurs: [link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest)[link]

Comment: what's the output of console.log($scope.lista) in your promise ?

Comment: When I load a screen, the $ scope.list = [], after the select component loads, there executes a function $ scope.loadFiliais, where it will feed my $ scope.list which with value:
`code`. 
(2) [Object, Object]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
length
:
2
`code`.

Comment: Solution found using **ng-if**, I edited the post and I put the form that it solved, but I do not know if it is the best form.

Comment: You could have tested for length property of lista as it's an array, instead of making it null.

Comment: I changed according to the hint, I am comparing an array: ** lista.length> 0 **

Answer (score 0):

An [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) function can change a preview of your HTML and have ruins consequences in cases of a doubtful or complex upload.
For quick searches like your case, a function has a very valid job.